# Getting name from other table with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
I have a table with logs:
LOGGING (300 rows):
- id
- type_id
- timestamp
- notes

And a table with logging types:
LOGGING_TYPES (4 rows):
- id
- typename
```

The field logging.type_id links to logging_types.id.

Now I have made this query:

```
SELECT logging.*,logging.types.tyopename 
FROM logging, logging_types 
JOIN logging_types ON logging.type_id=logging_types.id.
```

The result is only 4 rows since the types table contains only four records. I don't want that. I want the result to be 300 rows, and that the name of the logging type is displayed. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of using `INNER JOIN` is correct. The problem is that you mixing comma and `JOIN` syntaxes for joining tables. Use only one at a time. Try

```
SELECT l.*,
       t.typename 
  FROM logging l JOIN logging_types t
    ON l.type_id = t.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/697ec/1)** demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) like this:

```
SELECT l.*, lt.typename FROM Logging l
      LEFT JOIN Logging_Types lt
             ON l.type_id = lt.id
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aba2/9) with sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just `LEFT JOIN` them in correct way

```
SELECT a.*, b.tyopename 
FROM logging a 
LEFT JOIN logging_types b 
ON a.type_id=b.id
```